# UWP How to simplify view model for GridView and ListView

Tags: listview, gridview, view, model, uwp

I need to be able to view the same data in both a ListView and a GridView. I have a play solution that works using a Template 10 ViewModelBase. The bit I don't like about this solution is that I had the turn the data into ViewModel as well. This is because I unable find away of specifying the data binding in XAML DataTemplate.

I would like to know if there is any way of simplifying this so that each piece of data isn't a ViewModel (in this case the DummyData). I would ideally like to have only have the one ViewMode in this case MainPageViewModel and to only need to use the TestData property.

The XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="WindowsApp2.Views.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:interop="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop"
      xmlns:viewModels="using:WindowsApp2.ViewModels"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextDataTemplate" x:DataType="viewModels:DummyData">
            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding LastName}"
                            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Page.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainPageViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>


    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView Name="lvDummyData" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TextDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" />
            <GridView Name="gvDummyData" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TextDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

The ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Template10.Mvvm;

namespace WindowsApp2.ViewModels
{
    public class DummyData : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public ObservableCollection<DummyData> TestData { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            var dummyData = new List<DummyData>
                            {
                                new DummyData { FirstName = "Test Name 1", LastName = "Test Last Name 1" },
                                new DummyData { FirstName = "Test Name 2", LastName = "Test Last Name 2" },
                                new DummyData { FirstName = "Test Name 3", LastName = "Test Last Name 3" },
                                new DummyData { FirstName = "Test Name 4", LastName = "Test Last Name 4" },
                                new DummyData { FirstName = "Test Name 5", LastName = "Test Last Name 5" },
                                new DummyData { FirstName = "Test Name 6", LastName = "Test Last Name 6" }
                            };

            TestData = new ObservableCollection<DummyData>( dummyData );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean "each piece of data isn't a ViewModel (in this case the DummyData)". Do you mean you don't want `DummyData` class inherit from `ViewModelBase`? If so, you can remove it from your code. In you sample this won't have any effect.

Comment: What I want is not to have to inherit DummyData from ViewModelBase. What I would like to do is just reference it from the XAML using only the MainPageViewModel.TestData

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is not to have to inherit DummyData from ViewModelBase. What I would like to do is just reference it from the XAML using only the MainPageViewModel.TestData

In your sample, `DummyData` do not have to inherit from `ViewModelBase`, you can just define it like following:

```cs
public class DummyData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In Template 10, [`ViewModelBase`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Mvvm/ViewModelBase.cs) is usually used to support binding and navigation service. As your `DummyData` is a data model, there is no need to inherit from `ViewModelBase`. And since you are using {Binding} in your code, there is also no need to use **`x:DataType`**, you can also delete it. `x:DataType` is used for `{x:Bind}` to declare the type of a `DataTemplate`'s data object. For more info, please see **DataTemplate and x:DataType** in [Binding object declared using {x:Bind}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#binding-object-declared-using-x-bind).

Besides, if you want to implement property-change notifications for `DummyData`, you can inherit from [`BindableBase`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs) like following:

```cs
public class DummyData : BindableBase
{
    private string _FirstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set { Set(ref _FirstName, value); }
    }

    private string _LastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set { Set(ref _LastName, value); }
    }
}
```

By inheriting from `BindableBase`, you do not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface by yourself and helps to simplify your code.